# HTML Email MIME-type for plain text

Tags: html, email, mime

I have a client/friend who is preparing an email to send through agencyaccess.  They require an all-inclusive document with the html, and plain text versions of the email in one HTML document.  I have a basic understanding I think, but am a bit confused.  I generally use Mailchimp to handle my email marketing.

So we would use a regular html document with

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Email</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
 our html markup

</body>
</html>
```

but then is it somewhere below this that we declare an alternative mime-type for the plain text version, and then the email client chooses which to show?  And would the both of these have to be wrapped in a multipart/mixed mime-type?

I know this is probably pretty simple, but most of what I had read handled the MIME-type declaration in the PHP file sending the mail, but we need to differentiate inside this document.  Really just wondering how this should be structured.

Comment: "in one HTML document" It's not an HTML document anymore, if you include multipart documents. "just wondering how this should be structured" Look at the source code of some random email (`Ctrl + u` will display email source in many clients)

Comment: Use a library that will deal with the multipart/mime stuff. Don't do it manually. Last time I did this I used [`Email::MIME::CreateHTML`](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::MIME::CreateHTML), which has an example in the docs. That's not PHP though.

Comment: correct, I misspoke.  It would not be an html document, but a multipart document containing html.  I'll take a look at your suggestion though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it was confusion for nothing. The service implied that the user was expected to upload a single document to cover the both(which implies needed to specify MIME-types in the document), but this was not the case, as they required everything to fall inside html markup. The service itself was supposed to offer the additional step to insert the plain text version, and it was a bug on their part that they are working on. Hope that makes sense, but thanks for the responses guys